# How can I grep for files that have both expressions?

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to display files that contain more than one expression and exclude files that do not have all expressions.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Usually I do that sort of thing by running grep multiple times, something like

```
grep -l 'expression1' * | xargs grep -l 'expression2' | xargs grep -l 'expression3'
```

and so on.  It doesn't seem very efficient, and I wouldn't be surprised if there is a better way, but I don't know it.

Comment: With some domain knowledge (in this case "what regexp is least likely to match") and starting with that regexp, this is probably close to the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

egrep -r 'expression1|expression2|expression3' .

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have the -r you can just use grep over again on the results
grep expression1 * | grep expression 2 | grep expression 3